# Blender 2.8 Video editing - annotation

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, grease-pencil

Do you know if you can annotate a video in Blender?

I have tried to d + mouse draw, but I need to control when the grease pen stroke is shown.

I am trying to add circles to a video sequence, to bring attention to an area.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually render video with annotations, by clicking: "view" in your viewport for video editing.

And then do render sequence animation.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The annotation tool is an internal tool for the user, it is not for adding visual drawing to the rendered output.

In the VSE, you can add a scene strip, which means you can create a circle using geometry or a grease pencil object in the 3D view and add it to the VSE.

You can also add a single image to the VSE. So you can save a circle as a PNG with a transparent background and add that to the VSE.

Comment: can I also directly write on a video in such a way that my drawing/writing is animated as well?

Comment: @yogabonito The grease pencil can be animated and rendered, so yes you can add that result over a video, either with the VSE or the compositor. You would add a background image to the 3d view camera to see where you are drawing.

Comment: Thank you @sambler :) I have figured out how to do it with the compositor. How would it be possible in the VSE? (I mostly use the VSE anyway and would like to avoid the nodes ;))

Comment: (when I go to Add->Scene I only get "No Items available")

Comment: @yogabonito from 2.80 the VSE prevents adding the [current scene](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/scene_layout/scene/introduction.html) to the VSE (its a dependency thing) So you need two scenes, one with the grease pencil the other can be an empty scene to use in the VSE. Top right next to the render layers to create a new scene.

Comment: Thank you so much @sambler! :D